# Magento 2 - Custom customer address attributes not shown in order billing/shipping addresses

Tags: magento, magento2, magento2.4

When I create custom customer address attributes, do I need to add these attributes to order tables in database to be able to show them in order billing/shipping addresses or it should be just enough to add them to address templates in magento admin -> stores -> configuration -> customer configuration -> address templates.

Thanks in advance, Denis